# C++ Storing constant varibale names within a vector

Tags: c++, vector, struct, constants, preprocessor

My task is to write a preprocessor that replaces the constant variable with its actual value. To do this, I have created a struct and a vector to store the constant name and value. But unfortunately, I'm getting all kinds of compile errors. Can anyone spot any potential issues? Thank you in advance

```
using namespace std;
    
struct constantVariable 
{
    string constantName;
    string constantValue;
}; 

void defineReplace(string line)
{

    vector <constantVariable> constant;
    
    
    string token;
    
    stringstream stream(line);
    while(stream >> token)
    {
        
        if(token == "#define")
        {
        stream >> token;
        constant.constantName = token;
        stream >> token;
        constant.constantValue = token;
        break;
        }
    }
    
    constant.push_back(constant);
}
```

Comment: yes, the issue is that `constant` is a vector and not a constantVariable, so `constant.constantName` makes no sense

Comment: Do you see something seriously wrong with this line: `constant.push_back(constant);`? Can you explain what this line of code should be doing, in your own words? Can you try [explaining every line of your program to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)? I have every confidence in your rubber duck being able to explain all the problems with the shown code.

Comment: Name the vector `constants` and have a local variable `constantVariable constant;` defined inside the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a new local variable inside your reading loop like this:

```
    while(stream >> token)
    {
        
        if(token == "#define")
        {
        constantVariable addconstant;
        stream >> token;
        addconstant.constantName = token;
        stream >> token;
        addconstant.constantValue = token;
        constant.push_back(addconstant);
        }
    }
```

But take care with checking the input stream. It should not be done as easy as you did it... but that is another question.